TypeORM unaccent search without QueryBuilder
Does it exist a way to unaccent values in the database while searching a value in where condition without using QueryBuilder in TypeORM ?
I didn't tried anything since no documentation or FindOperator exists to unaccent database values
EDIT
I'm using a PostgreSQL database
